# 301 Redirect to assimilate one website into another

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a main website example.com and another website subsidary.com.
The subsidary.com website is to be phased out and redirects put in place.

`subsidary.com` will have its A record repointed to `example.com` and a domain added in cPanel for `example.com`

Most of the entries in htaccess are straightforward, of the form

```
Redirect 301 /old-page-1 https://example.com/new-page-1
Redirect 301 /old-page-2 https://example.com/new-page-2
Redirect 301 /old-page-3 https://example.com/new-page-1
...
```

where old-page-1, 2 and 3 **do not** exist as URLs on the new site

So far, so good. My problem is that I need to direct the home page of the old site to a specific page on the new site.

Obviously I can't do

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/new-landing-page-subsidary-com
```

How do I target the old URL so that someone requesting `https://subsidary.com` is correctly redirected to `https://example.com/new-landing-page-subsidary-com`

Comment: I would say I've done extensive searching for this but can only turn up the generalised '301 redirect one site to another' not dealing with the home page as a special case